# text-aling:left align:left in google android browser is making the text in column around %20 of the page how this can be fixed?

Tags: html, android-browser

Hello I have a problem with text-align: left or align: left no matter what I put the text get's stuck on the left side of the page in a big column how this can be fixed ?

example of the code:

```
<div class="maintext02"><span><p>text</p>
```

```
.maintext02 {
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#545454; line-height:25px; font-size:12px;
width:943px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
text-align:left;
```

}

Comment: Are you closing your `<span>` and `<div>` tags? Are you floating anything right?